# $f$ is continuous and $f(0)\ge f(x)$, for all $x\in [0,\delta]$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove (or disprove) the following statement:

$f:[0,\delta]\to [0,\infty[$, is a continuous function and $f(0)\ge f(x)$ for all $x$. Is there $\overline{\delta}<\delta$ such that $f$ is decreasing on $[0,\overline{\delta}]$?

It seems to be true but I am struggling to prove it.

I am trying to use contradiction but not successfully so far.

Comment: Maybe if $f$ was differentiable.

Comment: @KevinP.Barry No $f$ differentiable is not even a sufficient condition. See https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-function-whose-derivative-at-0-is-one-but-which-is-not-increasing-near-0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.

A counterexample is

$$f(x)= -x\left(1+\frac{1}{2} \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

The derivative is taking positive and negative values on intervals included in any neighborhood of zero.

You can even have a counterexample when $f$ is supposed to be differentiable. See https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-function-whose-derivative-at-0-is-one-but-which-is-not-increasing-near-0/.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't look like it's true.  Consider for example $f(x) = -2x + x \sin \left( \tfrac{1}{x} \right)$ for $x \ne 0$, and $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Or the Weierstrass function.